# Formula expression is required for attribute value error

Tags: apex, visualforce

I keep getting this error "Formula expression is required for attribute value" 
on this line `<apex:selectOptions value="2015"/>`

Why?

```
    <h1>Please Select a Year:</h1><p />
    <apex:selectList id="yearChosen" value="{!yearChosen}" multiselect="false" size="1">
        <apex:selectOptions value="2015"/>
        <apex:selectOptions value="2016"/>
        <apex:selectOptions value="2017"/>
        <apex:selectOptions value="2018"/>            
    </apex:selectList>
<p />
```

Comment: What is the value={!yearChosen} there in the apex:selectList? Either Method or variable?

Comment: This is all I have     public Integer yearChosen { get; set; }

Answer (score 1):

You should create a method for this...

with the below code, you can be able to select an option in UI Level

```
        <apex:selectOptions value="2015"/>
        <apex:selectOptions value="2016"/>
        <apex:selectOptions value="2017"/>
        <apex:selectOptions value="2018"/>
```

But to process them and to fetch them to the Particular value in Apex, It must be have some method to process...

See the below URL for example

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectList.htm

Hope this might helps...

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you used *<apex:selectOption**s**>* (plural) which requires you to provide a List<T> (or function returning a List) for the *value* parameter.

In your application, you actually just want to use *<apex:selectOption>* (singular) so that each usage is a single item.